# How to compute Shklyarov (aka "algebraic closed string") copairing on smooth schemes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth scheme over a field $k$. Then $HH_{*}(\operatorname{Perf}(X))$ (that is, Hochschild homology of the category of perfect complexes of sheaves on $X$, defined, for example, as the homology of the complex on page 7 of [Stefanich - Derived Morita theory and Hochschild Homology and Cohomology of DG Categories](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egermans/HH.pdf#page=7)) admits a copairing $$k \rightarrow HH_{*}(\operatorname{Perf}(X)) \otimes HH_{*}(\operatorname{Perf}(X))$$ defined by sending $1 \in k$ to the image of the class $[\mathrm{id}] \in HH_{*}(\operatorname{Perf}(X \times X))$ of $\mathrm{id}: \mathcal{O}_\Delta \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_\Delta$, under the map $$HH_{*}(\operatorname{Perf}(X \times X)) \xrightarrow{\sim} HH_{*}(\operatorname{Perf}(X)) \otimes HH_{*}(\operatorname{Perf}(X)).$$

What, concretely, is this copairing for, say, an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbf{C}$? E.g. what is the image of $1 \in \mathbf{C}$?  How about for $E \times \mathbf{A}^{1}_{\mathbf{C}}$?